# Цикл с конкретными условиями

Tags: php, база-данных, mariadb, redbeanphp

Нужен цикл, который будет выводить только те продукты, у которых столбик «раздел» в таблице с значением, скажем, - «техника».

Этот код выводит все продукты:

```
$length = R::count('products');
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "magnete");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products`");

for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
   while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<div class="product">';
    echo "<img src='".$r['image']."'>";
    echo "<h2>";
    echo $r['name'];
    echo "</h2>";
    echo "<p>";
    echo $r['price'];
    echo "</p>";
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="';
    echo $r['from'];
    echo '">на сайт</a>';
    echo "<a href='product.php?id='".$r['id']."''>больше</a>";
    echo "</div>";      
    }
}
```

Comment: Как называется столбец _"раздел"_ в mysql у Вас? Пока вижу у Вас тут $r['image'] , $r['name'] , $r['price'] , $r['from'] и $r['id']

Comment: называется category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$length = R::count('products');  // Это можно убрать.
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "magnete");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products`");

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($r['category'] == "техника") {
        echo '<div class="product">';
        echo "<img src='" . $r['image'] . "'>";
        echo "<h2>";
        echo $r['name'];
        echo "</h2>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo $r['price'];
        echo "</p>";
        echo '<a target="_blank" href="';
        echo $r['from'];
        echo '">на сайт</a>';
        echo "<a href='product.php?id='" . $r['id'] . "''>больше</a>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) as $r) {
    echo '<div class="product">';
        echo "<img src='".$r['image']."'>";
        echo "<h2>";
        echo $r['name'];
        echo "</h2>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo $r['price'];
        echo "</p>";
        echo '<a target="_blank" href="';
        echo $r['from'];
        echo '">на сайт</a>';
        echo "<a href='product.php?id='".$r['id']."''>больше</a>";
        echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: в таком случаи он выводит столько продуктов сколько столбцов есть в таблице

Comment: Проверьте ваше решение.